# How do you make parentheses match height when they're split between lines in LaTeX math?

Tags: split, latex, parentheses, tex

Consider the following example

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        f = & \left( \frac{a}{b} + \right. \\
                   & \left. c \right) + d 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

In the result, the left parenthesis on the first line is very large, because of the fraction inside. In the second line, since there is no fraction, the parenthesis is small.

How can I make the one on the second line match the one on the first line in height?

Comment: I seem to recall something like a "ghost" command, but I cannot find anything on google or in the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `\vphantom`, it makes a vertical space equal to its argument and no horizontal space:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        f = & \left( \frac{a}{b} + \right. \\
                   & \left. \vphantom{\frac{a}{b}} c \right) + d 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

(I recommend `\vphantom` over `\phantom` in this case because `\phantom` adds horizontal space that you don't need.)

For a lot of great advice on typesetting mathematics, have a look at [Math mode](https://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) by Herbert Voß.

Comment: Yeah, I actually saw that when I found phantom on google. But you're right. Bonus points for the awesome reference. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I like that document a lot.  Anyway, I would have made my post into a comment, but I felt that there was enough independent information to make it a reply.

Answer (score 3):

Oh. It's the \phantom{} command

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        f = & \left( \frac{a}{b} + \right. \\
                   & \left. \phantom{\frac{a}{b}} c \right) + d 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use \big( \big) to set the size specifically.

The order goes (, \big(, \Big(, \bigg(, \Bigg( for increasing bigness.

Comment: yeah, I've used that before, but I don't like having to specify manually... I'm always afraid of having to change the stuff inside and then not notice that the parentheses don't match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `\vphantom{}` command

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    f = & \left( \frac{a}{b} + \right. \\
               & \left. \phantom{\frac{a}{b}} c \right) + d 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```